# Conversion of 1-D array to 2-D array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have tried to convert a 1-D array to a 2-D array.  For example, if the 1-D array looks like this 1 2 3 4; the 2-D array should look like this
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 0
1 2 0 0
1 0 0 0 
For this, I have tried the following code:

```
void main()
{
    int n;  
    cout<<"\nEnter the size of the 1D array";
    cin>>n;
    int *p=new int[n];
    int *m=new int[n][n];
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>p[i];
    }
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        m[i][j]=0;
    }
    for(int i=n;i>=0;i--)
    {
        int x=0;
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            m[x][j]=p[x];
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S: I have excluded all header files, I don't need help with that.  Please tell me the errors I have made in the logic. I am using Turbo C++ 4.5.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problems you have with the code you show? Do you get build errors? Crashes when running? Unexpected results? Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger? And please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am getting build errors.

Comment: A first error would be `int *m=new int[n][n];`. As your compiler probably told you, a matrix is actually a `int **`, not a `int*`. Though "I get build errors" isn't exactly descriptive to what the issue is. Please describe the problem precisely. E.g. **what** build-errors you get, and mark the line in which they happen.

Comment: Then you need to *tell* us the errors you get. Copy-paste them into the body of your question as text. And please edit the code you show to point out where the errors are (for example by adding comments).

Comment: I am supposed to build a dynamic array, so that must be a pointer.

Comment: @Sandipan your right at the point that a dynamic array is represented via a pointer. Nevertheless a pointer can be pointing to another pointer, like in `int**`. Those pointers are then used to represent a 2D-array for example.

Comment: @Paul a matrix is not an `int**` at all.

Comment: @Quentin that's not what I said. I said a matrix/2D-array needs to be stored in a pointer of a pointer at least (oversimplified). That's ignoring a few details, but I'd keep it simple, since OP apparently is rather new to this topic. Anyways, I didn't say anything about equivalence

Answer (score 0):

Just pointing out the errors

1. You defined variables i and j twice.(probably will just pop a warning)
2. In this loop, i should start with n-1.

   ```
   for(int i=n;i>=0;i--)
   {
   int x=0;
   for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
   {
   m[x][j]=p[x];
   x++;
   }
   }
   ```
3. In above loop, you are just assigning diagonal elements again and again because variable x and variable j will increase at same rate.

Comment: So what would be the correct algorithm here, please help me out.(This isn't a homework question)